# When I access my Default Web Site with my fresh install of IIS 10, it redirects me to "http://localhost/installation/index.php". Why?

Tags: php, windows-10, localhost, iis-10

When I access my Default Web Site with my fresh install of Windows 10 IIS 10, it redirects me to "http://localhost/installation/index.php". Why?

Even though I have a "localhost/index.htm", which says "Hello World"...

That index.php is also a blank page...

Given what I could drudge up about that URL, is it because I don't have any web server software installed, like Joomla or Apache?

Comment: Have you checked your Web Application root directory in IIS?

Comment: @M_Becker - How do I do that? Is it the ASP.Net Application Settings? That's empty...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Trace that who gives you the 30x responses and it should be clear.

Comment: IIS is web server software, just like Apache.  Joomla is not web server software.  It is a CMS, that runs on PHP/MySQL and requires a web server, like IIS/Apache/etc.   Check your bindings, and make sure you're actually getting content served from your local IIS host.  Also, make sure you have a default document set which includes "index.htm"

Comment: Check out "Adding a website to IIS" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/creating-websites/scenario-build-a-static-website-on-iis#step-2-add-a-website

Comment: @pendo - Thanks for the Default Document tip. I blanked my Index.php, and it stopped redirecting me. Now to figure out why it was in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> That index.php is also a blank page...

Is the problem. You need index.php to eventually you to "localhost/index.htm", and it can't do that if it's empty.